# Getting an ANR error on a MediaPlayer Service

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-anr-dialog

I have a service which plays music/video using MediaPlayer APIs. According to some users, in some cases – it happens while playing audio on the background –, but, trying to reproduce the issue **– it doesn't happen always –**, I have to play a video (eventhough that can also happen while playing a video or a song), pause it, and then press the back button. The MediaPlayer is killed, (I see a log from myself, and a GC event).

Then I get a ANR dialog. Eventhough everything feels responsive.

I tried with StrictMode and all I get is the following, I tried to set the activity as launchMode: **singleInstance** but this doesn't help either.

```
08-07 17:38:05.510: E/StrictMode(5232): class com.ifrins.hipstacast.HipstacastVideoEpisodePlayer; instances=3; limit=1
08-07 17:38:05.510: E/StrictMode(5232): android.os.StrictMode$InstanceCountViolation: class com.ifrins.hipstacast.HipstacastVideoEpisodePlayer; instances=3; limit=1
08-07 17:38:05.510: E/StrictMode(5232):     at android.os.StrictMode.setClassInstanceLimit(StrictMode.java:1)
```

I attach different ANR stack traces: [1](http://pastebin.com/MnuNesaF) – [2](http://pastebin.com/z5cb02gX) – [3](http://pastebin.com/jxcdnhDu) – [4](http://pastebin.com/EfNP4KUs)

I don't know where to start from with those stack traces, they seem fine to me. Could you point me where I should look?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Any luck? Also, are you doing anything such as seeking after preparing, etc? Are you playing remote files or local ones?